# How to post array of single value in alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have to post json object.
One important thing, I have to post array of single value.
look at below code.

```swift
var pagingOption: [String: Any] = ["page": page,
                                   "rowsPerPage": 20,
                                   "sort": ["id": sortOption.rawValue,
                                            "direction": "DESC"],
                                   "searchStatues": ["accept"]]
```

`searchStatuses` is must array. But If I send this code, `searchStatuses` is not posted array.
If I add more value like this

```swift
var pagingOption: [String: Any] = ["page": page,
                                   "rowsPerPage": 20,
                                   "sort": ["id": sortOption.rawValue,
                                            "direction": "DESC"],
                                   "searchStatues": ["accept", "asdf", "asdf"]]
```

Then delivered array.
If I have only single value, How can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
let searchValues: [String] = []

searchValues = ["accept", "asdf", "asdf"]

var pagingOption: [String: Any] = ["page": page,
                                   "rowsPerPage": 20,
                                   "sort": ["id": sortOption.rawValue,
                                            "direction": "DESC"],
                                   "searchStatues": searchValues]
```

Comment: I don't have multi value. I have only one value.

Comment: But that way it doesn't delivered to an array as I said. I want to deliver it as an array even if there is only one value.

Comment: It will be posted as array because the searchValue variable is initialize as array of String. Can I see the response once you posted this parameters?

Comment: oh sorry. I have mistake. I made a mistake typing. You are right I am so sorry.